# How can I add Salesforce as a data source in Datagrip?

Tags: salesforce, datagrip

I use Datagrip for SQL development. Recently I've had to work with Salesforce SQL (aka `SOQL`), but there doesn't seem to be an IDE as useful as Datagrip.

So: I'd like to add Salesforce as a data source to Datagrip, just as I would a Postgres or MySQL database.

Is this possible to do, with an extension or otherwise?

I know https://jetforcer.com/ exists, but it seems to fall short on two counts:

(a) it's apparently just a UI that lives in JetBrains apps, so I don't think it'd fit as seamlessly in Datagrip workflow as I'd like

(b) It costs $60. I don't need to do any actual Salesforce development, so paying $60 just to run queries against Salesforce isn't ideal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DataGrip can support any database that have JDBC driver.
First of all, you need to find JDBC driver for the database. In your case that can be:

http://reliersoft.com/download/salesforce-jdbc-driver/

Then follow the instructions of generic-JDBC data source configuration:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/connecting-to-a-database.html#vertica_as_unsupported_dbms

URL should be like `jdbc:sforce://<hostname>`
(More options are available in driver's docs http://reliersoft.com/salesforce-jdbc-driver-documentation/)

After that you can run queries and view data.
If something does not work as expected, please file an issue in our [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue)

Comment: The link for JDBC is dead...